# Remove Missing return type on function warning from esLint for TypeScript

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I am using **eslint** with TypeScript.

I would like to switch off the check about the explicit return type for functions.

I have added to `rules` in **.eslintrc.js** the property `"@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": "off"`.

Now the same warning is generated by the rule `"@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types"` which I do not want to switch off since I want to check that parameters passed to functions are actually typed.

Is there a way to remove the **Missing return type on function** warning without switching off also `"@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types"`?

This is my **.eslintrc.js**

```
module.exports = {
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',  
    plugins: ["deprecation", '@typescript-eslint'],
    extends: [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
        "prettier",
    ],
    parserOptions: {
        ecmaVersion: 2018,  
        sourceType: 'module',  
    },
    rules: {
        "deprecation/deprecation": "warn",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-object-literal-type-assertion": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": "off"
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the rule's docs here: https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/explicit-module-boundary-types. As of writing there aren't any that would disable the rule for all return types.

If you wanted to, you could https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/new/choose asking for this. Be sure to fill out the appropriate template in full (*✨ New Rule Option or Additional Check*).